# Best practice to load Images from FB storage with low traffic

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i need some advice about the best practice to store and load
objects which consists of primitive data and an image. I already implemented a working version but iam not sure if this way is fine.

The app:
A user have a collection of cars and can add or delete them to there collection and view details about this cars.

An example of such an car object.

```
Car
  -Name:"Golf 42"
  -Manufacturer:"VW"
  -Image:The image
```

Current status:
all non Image data is stored inside my Firebase realtime database and get queried whenever the app starts/a user sign in.
However iam not sure whats the best practice to store the the Image itself.

I know i can store the Image into the Firebase Storage Database and download and bind them to my local view with FirebaseUi and glide
(as shown here https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)

That is what iam doing right now,but iam not sure if this is the best practice for pictures inside a collection which might be loaded several times while the use interact with the app.
Or at least once on every app start.

My second idea was to download "missing" images from the FB Storage in a structured way.
when a user now add a new cars to his collection the app will download and save the image on the device.
And the views always use these stored Images in order to save mobile traffic.
In my mind this should improve the performance a bit.
I Display the Cars inside a recyclerview. Typical all users should have just a bunch of cars in her collection, i dont think a lot user will even collect 100 cars.

However iam not sure if this is a good practice or rather stay with this firebaseUi Glide stuff.

Comment: Glide will cache for you automatically.

Comment: Can i force Glide to cache Images before even attach them to a View? Right now i encountered the following Problem: User starts the app and signs in. When the Collection (a Recyclerview with Images) get pressed, the Images (or at least some) are not complete downlaoded from the firebase storage yet. Therefore they are blank. After a while (some seconds or so) the imageview can be populated.

Answer (score 0):

@Rantir Glide Caches the images for you by default, you can configure them as per ur needs refer (https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation) and some more info @ (https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics)
And w.r.t getting Blank images, U can use "Placehloder" in Glide, refer (https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-placeholders-fade-animations)

And w.r.t Best Practice, I can't assure u is it a best practice or not, but u can try one thing that i used once in my app. It is that u can store your FbStorage Image's refrence/URi's in the FBDatabase & then refer FBDatabase ref for poupuklating your views using ValueEventListner, this way u can have better control over the Images part of ur app & in addtion to this you can Also try Enabling FB Persistence (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) also to get better experience